# Editing Host file to bypass a holding page

Tags: windows-7, hosts-file

For the last two years I have secured Glastonbury tickets by editing my host file with:

194.168.131.174 glastonbury.seetickets.com

This year, this has caused that particular website to be unavailable. Any other website comes up fine.  When I remove the host file command I can again access said website.

So have they put in place a method to block anyone with that address in their hostfile accessing the website, would there have been a way around it?

Thank you

Comment: Did you check if they changed the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They may have changed their sever location, which means their IP address may have changes. A DNS lookup returns the following IP Addresses used for glastonbury.seetickets.com:

194.168.202.218 - 194.168.202.202 - 194.168.202.201

Comment: Yes, I was aware there may have been a different IP address. I was curious as to why no webpage loaded.  For example if I change host to 194.168.131.174 www.seetickets.com. The main seetickets page will still load but with '194.168.131.174 glastonbury.seetickets.com' that particular site does not load.

Comment: I did the same to my hosts file, and it redirects me to the same page as without it. They may have fixed your bypass internally.

Comment: Thanks Caraxian.  I have tried again and sure enough, it loads with host file attached.  It seems somehow they have managed to block people with edited host file during the actual sale itself

Comment: Have your considered perhaps your hosts entry was cached in the DNS and would not associate a new IP with a domain until the cache expires or you flush the local DNS cache?

Answer (score 0):

If I edit my hosts file as above I can see http://glastonbury.seetickets.com/content/gfl-worthy-view

which is the page everyone sees until the tickets go on sale, so the method should work on Sunday when tickets go on sale. You must be entering incorrect details if you are not seeing the site.